# Calling ASP.net function with parameters from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, data-binding

I have two ASP.Net functions in server side (code behind):

```
string GetError();
string GetErrorAtIndex(int, int);
```

In client side code, I use javascript to call the first function and it works fine

```
function test() {
    var x = <%= GetError() %>;
    alert('x');
}
```

However, am unable to call the second function which takes two parameters:

```
function test2() {
    var param1 = 10;
    var param2 = 100;
    var x = <%= GetErrorAtIndex(param1, param2) %>;
    alert('x');
}
```

I get the error

```
CS0103: The name 'param1' does not exist in the current context
```

I understand that this is because the javascript local variable won't have visibility in the ASP.Net call. I then thought of using HiddenFields to store/pass parameters, but am unable to do that.

Any hints/inputs would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that you don't understand the relationship between server and client.

Comment: @crush: Apart from your negative tone and no rather helpful information, I'd like to point that I have mentioned clearly that am looking for passing variables using hidden fields, without using a postback. Am sure even you don't understand that and that's why the trolling comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the __doPostBack() method to send back Event Targets and arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Because `param1` is a JavaScript variable not an ASP.NET variable.

Comment: If you read my question correctly, I already mentioned this as the last point. I fully understand that javascript vars won't have visibility in asp.net and vice versa. What I asked is of a 'way' to somehow pass this variable, without using AJAX PageMethods etc, like using ASP.Net hidden fields, which can be updated in javascript and ASP.net alike.